# How to get result from code in a -command option

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

reference : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tcl_Programming/Tk_examples#A_little_calculator

I'm the beginner Tcl Language.
I'll try to make factorial procedure this calculator code,

using button "!"

an error occurred like this:

```
invalid command name "if{x<2}"
invalid command name "if{x<2}"
    while executing
"if{x<2} {
 return 1
} else "
    (procedure "fac" line 2)
    invoked from within
"fac {$row}"
    invoked from within
".20 invoke"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list $w invoke]"
    (procedure "tk::ButtonUp" line 24)
    invoked from within
"tk::ButtonUp .20"
    (command bound to event)
```

and Using "!" at keypad error code like this

```
    wrong # args: should be "fac x"
    wrong # args: should be "fac x"
        while executing
    "fac"
        (command bound to event)
```

in this code

```
package require Tk
    wm title . Calculator
    grid [entry .e -textvar e -just right] -columnspan 5
    bind .e <Return> =
    bind .e <!> fac

    set n 0

    foreach row {
       {7 8 9 + -}
       {4 5 6 * /}
       {1 2 3 ( )}
       {C 0 . = !}
    } {
       foreach key $row { 
           switch -- $key {
               =       {set cmd =}
               C       {set cmd {set clear 1; set e ""}}
               !       {set cmd {[fac {$row}]}} 
               default {set cmd "hit $key"}
           }
           lappend keys [button .[incr n] -text $key -command $cmd]
       }
       eval grid $keys -sticky we ;#-padx 1 -pady 1
       set keys [list]
    }
    grid .$n -columnspan 2 ;# make last key (=) double wide
    proc = {} {
       regsub { =.+!} $::e "" ::e ;# maybe clear previous result
       if [catch {set ::res [expr [string map {/ *1.0/} $::e]]}] {
           .e config -fg red 
       }
       append ::e = $::res 
       .e xview end
       set ::clear 1
    }
    proc fac {x} {
    if{$x<2} {
     return 1
    } else 
    {
    return $x[fac[incr x-1]]
    }
    }

    # expr {$x<2? x 1: $x*[fac [incr x -1]]}}

    proc hit {key} {
       if $::clear {
           set ::e ""
           if ![regexp {[0-9().]} $key] {set ::e $::res}
           .e config -fg black
           .e icursor end
           set ::clear 0
       }
       .e insert end $key
    }
    set clear 0
    focus .e           ;# allow keyboard input
    wm resizable . 0 0
```

So, I can't get result procedure at -command or cmd.

How to get return procedure result using cmd, -command option in Tcl?

Sorry about hard to read English, Thanks.

P.S. I think about "cmd", is a likely Other Language(like a C style) in "Macro"?

Comment: The `cmd` tag is about the Microsoft Windows command shell processor. If this question is not about Windows, the `cmd` tag should be removed.

Comment: Try inserting a space between `if` and `{$x<2}`; the `{` after `else` also needs to be on the same line.

Comment: @PeterLewerin I'll try this but same error occur 
Thanks to help

Comment: I've looked closer at the code now. Apart from the problems I mentioned, the code for inserting a factorial into the expression is broken. The code needs to identify the last term and use that as argument to fac. As it is, fac gets the leftover value in $row. Defining a new fac math function which can be used internally in expr might make it easier. See http://wiki.tcl.tk/20279 and search for "factorial".

Comment: I've got rid of tags that would definitely mislead readers…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that this:

```
proc fac {x} {
if{$x<2} {
 return 1
} else 
{
return $x[fac[incr x-1]]
}
}
```

does not compute a factorial. Yes, it's declaring a procedure, `fac`, but the procedure's implementation script is wrong in multiple ways that are tantamount to syntax errors. Let's fix the obvious places where you've got missing spaces or extra newlines first:

```
proc fac {x} {
if {$x<2} {
 return 1
} else {
return $x[fac [incr x -1]]
}
}
```

That will now compute *something* (we've got rid of the syntax problems by adding a space between `if` and its first argument, between `x` and `-1` in the arguments to `incr`, between `fac` and `[incr …]` in the recursive call, and getting rid of the extra newline after `else`) but it is still not what you want as it doesn't multiply `$x` by `[fac [incr x -1]]`; adding in that (with `[expr {… * …}]`) gives us this:

```
proc fac {x} {
if {$x<2} {
 return 1
} else {
return [expr {$x * [fac [incr x -1]]}]
}
}
```

Now we've got an actual functioning factorial! Let's just quickly tidy up the indentation for clarity:

```
proc fac {x} {
    if {$x<2} {
        return 1
    } else {
        return [expr {$x * [fac [incr x -1]]}]
    }
}
```

There are more efficient ways to implement factorial, but at least that's a clean working example now.

---

In general, when fixing your scripts you should fix the syntax blunders first (Tcl cares about spaces and newlines and the difference between them), then your semantic errors (e.g., a missing multiply), and then your indentation. But sometimes fixing your indentation makes the syntax errors more obvious, so that order isn't a strict rule!

You might want to find and install a copy of the [nagelfar tool](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9064). That does syntax analysis and will find all sorts of mistakes in code for you.